# Spring Data JPA to return List of Dates with a specified range (Start Date && End Date)

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

Currently, I am trying to return a list of Objects with a Date that falls into a range that is given by parameters... However, when I run my rest api call, nothing is returned. I am not sure if I am doing this Spring JPA request correctly and decided to get some feedback whether or not something I did is incorrect.

Here's some brief pseudocode:

Object Model

```
public class mResult{
/* other variables */
LocalDate runDate;
}
```

Repo

```
public interface mResultRepository extends CrudRepository<mResult,String> {
    List<mResult> findAllByRunDateBetween(LocalDate startDate,LocalDate endDate);
}
```

Service

```
mResultRepository mRepository;

public List<mResult> getAllBetweenDates(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate){
     return mRepository.findAllByRunDateBetween(startDate,endDate);
 }
```

My repo contains JSON objects for example:

```
{"runDate": "2019-02-05"}
{"runDate": "2019-02-06"}
{"runDate": "2019-02-10}
```

If my range is 2019-02-01 to 2019-02-09, then it should only return those in this range. However, when I run my API request, nothing is returned. Is my Spring JPA request correct? TIA

Comment: What's your datasource in your case? MongoDb?
I think you just have to add annotations in your model to say to JPA in which table or collection you want to get the data with something like :

@Entity
@Table(name="yourtable")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added an @DateTimeFormat annotation to my controller. Turns out the Spring JPA Request was correct, but it wasn't taking in my "yyyy-MM-dd" format.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue some time back I try/find to get the solution from the database level, but I didn't find any appropriate way to solve at DB level, So I would prefer it solve it from Java side as a sample code given below.

```
List<LocalDate> runningDates = Stream.iterate(startDate, date -> date.plusDays(1))
            .limit(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(startDate, endDate.plusDays(1)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I believe that it helps you.